# jQuery animation is not working TypeError: x.easing[this.easing] in jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, jquery-easing

I am working on a wordpress theme and stuck with a strange issue.

This is the site I am working on http://dalya.go-demo.com/

I want to expand the menu on clicking on the menu button in right side. And than want to close it on clicking on the close button.

See my code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $ = jQuery;

    function closeNav() {
        $('.close-nav').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.nav-area').children('nav').hide( 'slide', { direction: "right" }, 500);
            $(this).addClass('open-nav');
            $(this).removeClass('close-nav');
            openNav();
        });
    }

closeNav();

    function openNav() {
        $('.open-nav').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.nav-area').children('nav').show( 'slide', { direction: "right" }, 500);
            $(this).addClass('close-nav');
            $(this).removeClass('open-nav');
            closeNav();
        });
    }

openNav();

    $('.nav-area ul').children('li').children('a').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('span').animate({top:'-54px'});
        $(this).children('div.animated').show( 'slide', {direction: "up"}, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('span').animate( {top:'0px'} );
        $(this).children('div.animated').hide( 'slide', { direction: "up" } , 500);
    });

});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error: TypeError: x.easing[this.easing] is not a function Source File:
>   .../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2 Line: 5

I have tested all the possible solution available here on this forum but no success.

- jQuery is added.
- jQuery UI is added.
- jQuery Easing is added.
- No double jquery is added.

The same code is working fine in my HTML version of the site but in the Wordpress version I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to enque the jquery easing plugin.

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/